# Is there a faster way to delete a MinIO bucket than `mc rb`

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, minio, object-storage

I have a bucket in MinIO with 1M objects of about 8KiB.
Which is stored on a single node (ec2 m5.large) with a single ec2 io2 disk .

If I delete the bucket using the following command, it takes an incredibly long time:

`mc rb myminio/my-bucket-1 --force --dangerous`

I was wondering if there is a way to delete a bucket in a faster / more efficient way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your buckets folder

```
cd /var/minio/data
```

Delete your bucket

```
sudo rm -rf yourbucketname
```

will delete bucket and its content

then restart your minio service